# Can you get the execution time of the last program you run in bash?

Tags: bash, benchmarking, timing

I forgot to run a script using `time` so I don't know how much did it take. The script never completed, I stopped with `ctrl+c` after a while.

It is the last program I run in the terminal, and since then I entered no commands.
I was wondering if bash automatically stored the execution time of the last program run.

I don't need the time for benchmark purposes, so I don't need a great precision. Does bash (or linux somewhere) store information like "you started this script at this time and stopped it at this other time"?

I tried looking on SO but only find questions on how to time a program, not on how to get the "rough" time it took after you run it without using `time`.

Comment: If only you *did* enter a command right afterwards. Bash does record history, and you can make it print those timestamps by setting `HISTTIMEFORMAT` to an appropriate value. `export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%T ' ; history` will give you a history of commands, with timestamps. Duration, however, is not recorded (the closest thing to that is the shell start time, stored in `SECONDS`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert that would have been really helpful to know in advance! Write down your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: you don't need to `export` a permanent modification, you can set HISTTIMEFORMAT for one run of the command with `HISTTIMEFORMAT='%T ' history`.  But yeah, that's not an answer to this exact question; the shell only records start times, not end times.  (Or at least doesn't report end times that way)

Comment: @PeterCordes sure, but it's still a good solution. I wasn't benchmarking and a precision in the order of minutes would've been fine. I wish I knew I could have just run a command and compute the difference between the start times.

Comment: Another approach *before* hitting control-C is to use `ps` to see the start time of the process, if find something still running when you expected it to be done.